# OpenGL Won't Change Texture

Tags: c++, opengl

My textures wont change and i'm not sure why. This my Texture  Loader.h

```
    class TextureLoader
{
private:
    GLuint* Texture;
    std::map<std::string, GLuint*> TextureMap;
public:
    TextureLoader(){};
    ~TextureLoader()
    {
        delete Texture;
    }
    bool LoadTexture(std::string Source);
    GLuint* GetImage(std::string TextureID);    
    bool CheckTextureExsist(std::string TextureID);
};
```

This is the CPP.

```
bool TextureLoader::LoadTexture(std::string Source)
{
    //Bind the texture to load in.
    Texture = new GLuint;
    glGenTextures (1, Texture);
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, *Texture);

    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //Width, Height and Components of the image.
    int x, y, n;

    //Set pixel format
    int force_channels = 4;

    //Load data into the char.
    unsigned char*  image_data = stbi_load (
        Source.c_str(), &x, &y, &n, force_channels);

    //Check too see if the image loaded.
    if (!image_data) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not load %s\n", Source);
        return false;
    }

    //Copy the image data to the selected target.
    glTexImage2D (
        GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        x,
        y,
        0,
        GL_RGBA,
        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        image_data
        );
    free (image_data);

    TextureMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, GLuint*>(Source,Texture));
    return true;
}

GLuint* TextureLoader::GetImage(std::string TextureID)
{
    return TextureMap.find(TextureID)->second;
}

bool TextureLoader::CheckTextureExsist(std::string TextureID)
{

    if(TextureMap.find(TextureID) == TextureMap.end())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
        return true;
}
```

This is how i am drawing.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *TextureID);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT , GL_AMBIENT, Ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT , GL_DIFFUSE, Diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT , GL_SPECULAR, Specular);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT , GL_SHININESS, Shininess);

    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,&Vertices[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,&Normals[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0,&TextureCoords[0]);

    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(Scale[0],Scale[1],Scale[2]);
    glTranslatef(Translate[0],Translate[1],Translate[2]);
    glRotatef(Rotate[0],Rotate[1],Rotate[2],Rotate[3]);     
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,(GLsizei)(Vertices.size()/3));
    glPopMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
```

The TextureID gets passed the pointer, of the texture handle . The handle does change during run time to the different handles but it does draws the last texture that i loaded in, regardless of texture handle.

Comment: Why are you mixing `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` and `GL_TEXTURE_2D`? That is likely the problem. Also, why did you make the `Texture` member variable a pointer? You can just call `glGenTextures(1, &Texture)` on a GLuint.

Comment: Where is the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` ? And I set Texture to a pointer as `Texture = new GLuint;` will generate a new address. Other wise when I called `TextureMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, GLuint*>(Source,Texture));` It would just keep pushing back the same memory address and when a new texture is loaded in all the textures would change. Currently when the textures are pushed back `Texture` is a different memory address every time.

Comment: It's on line 4 of your `LoadTexture` function. Obviously you would change the map to store `GLuint` instead of `GLuint*` in that case.

Comment: Thank you the `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` was causing the error very bad mistake. And i could de-reference the `Texture` when i insert to the map but it wouldn't make any difference. It would just store a number rather then an address.

Comment: It would make the difference of not needlessly using pointers and making your program more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is binding to `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP` in your `LoadTexture` function:

```
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, *Texture);
```

Change that to

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *Texture);
```

I would also suggest to use `GLuint` instead of a `GLuint*` and store that into the map. The only reason `glGenTextures` takes a pointer is because it can also output to an array of `GLuint`.